# Arcpy walk not creating full list

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to create a CSV file of all spatial data in a directory structure using arcpy walk as in the below code.
However, when the code is run on a large file system it keeps stopping after a limited number of records. The problem was occurring in different places in different directory structures. After running it numerous times on the same dir structure, it was always occurring in the same place. There is nothing wrong with the files themselves.

```
def fileListing():
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(outputLocation, fileName), "w") as csv:
            # write out the column headers
            csv.write("Layer Name" + "," + "Layer Type" + "," + "Location" + "," + "Spatial Reference" + "\n" )

            walk = arcpy.da.Walk(inputLocation, datatype="Any", type="All")

            for root, dirs, files in walk:
                for f in files:
                    desc = arcpy.Describe(root + "\\" + f)
                    descDataType = desc.dataType
                    print(descDataType)
                    try:
                        descSR = removeChars(desc.SpatialReference.name)
                    except AttributeError:
                            continue
                    descName = removeChars(desc.name)
                    descCatPath = removeChars(desc.catalogPath)
                    #write info to text file
                    csv.write(descName + "," + descDataType + "," + descCatPath + "," + descSR + "\n")
        csv.close()
    except Exception as e:
    print("type error: " + str(e))
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Having run the script on the same directory structure numerous times it keeps failing at record number 225. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that particular record. It is a shapefile which loads into ArcMap fine.

The following error keeps occurring in PyScripter.

[image: PyScripter Error]

Comment: I don't see removeChars in base Python. Do you have another module imported?

Comment: What is the result of print statements added to your code? This can be used to determine the last action taken before it fails.  Also are there any error messages?

Comment: So, which is it: "The files / location stopped at changes" or "it keeps failing at record number 225"?

Comment: Any errors/exceptions reported?

Comment: Hi Smiller, The removeChars function isn't the problem. would have been nice and simple if it had been. Tried it without and same problem occurred.

Comment: Tom, Both. The problem was occurring in different places in different directory structures. After running it numerous times on the same dir structure, it was always occurring in the same place.

Comment: Son of a Beach, The PyScripter keeps reporting that the Remote Interpreter has been Reinitialised. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: When running in PyScripter the following error keeps occurring;

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question when you dont add all relevant code (removeChars) and we dont have you data to test with. You need to debug it yourself with print statements etc.

Comment: Could you try to run the script outside PyScripter (i.e. from a command line)?

Comment: Hi Berend, I have run the individual components against a single feature class at the ArcGIS python command line and it works fine. No errors or problems. When the script is run on the command line, i.e. writing the full function on the command line, it fails at the same point but without any error messages. It works with a small subset of data but not the full data. I'm not sure if there is a limit to the number of features that can be processed or whether there is a problem with the data. From my limited arcpy experience, it looks more like the data, though not sure how to deal with it.